# error with appending to a file and using an array

Tags: python, arrays, append

I have written this code:

```
    class component(object):

      def __init__(self,
                   name = None,
                   height = None,                 
                   width = None):

        self.name = name        
        self.height = height
        self.width = width

class system(object):

      def __init__(self,
                   name = None,                 
                   lines = None,
                   *component):

        self.name = name
        self.component = component

        if lines is None:
                self.lines = []
        else:
                            self.lines = lines

      def writeTOFile(self,
                      *component):
        self.component = component

        line =" "
        self.lines.append(line)

        line= "#----------------------------------------- SYSTEM ---------------------------------------#" 
        self.lines.append(line)


Component1 = component ( name = 'C1',
                         height = 500,
                         width = 400)
Component2 = component ( name = 'C2',
                         height = 600,
                         width = 700)

system1 = system(Component1, Component2)
system1.writeTOFile(Component1, Component2)
```

and I get the error :

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Work\trial2.py", line 46, in <module>
    system1.writeTOFile(Component1, Component2)
  File "C:\Python27\Work\trial2.py", line 32, in writeTOFile
    self.lines.append(line)
AttributeError: 'component' object has no attribute 'append'
```

And I don't really know how to fix it.

Also is there a way for defining my system1 as system(Component) where component = [Component1, Component2, ...Componentn] ?

Thanks in adavance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got things out of order in your `__init__`:

```
  def __init__(self, *component, **kwargs):

    self.name = kwargs.get('name')
    self.component = component

    self.lines = kwargs.get('lines', [])
```

Will work. You need `lines` and `name` to be after the `*` item that collects the component.

In Python 2, you can't then have named attributes after a `*`, so you need to instead use `**kwargs` and `get('name')` and `get('lines')` from the `kwargs`.

`get` just returns `None` if you don't supply a default, so you'll get `self.name = None` here. If you want to specify a default name, you can do

```
    self.name = kwargs.get('name', 'defaultname')
```

like I did for `lines`.

Answer (score 1):

in line 32 you use `self.lines.append(line)`.

But lines is a member of the class `system` initialized with `Component2`, which type is the class `component` that does not have the method `append`.

Comment: This doesn't tell him how to fix the problem.

Comment: You're right, reading your answer i noticed that his real problem  was the order, and that `Component2` was not supposed to be `lines`. My answer is pretty useless, im sorry

Comment: In fact I didn't understand the error, cos I thought append is like a general function in python... so therefore I wouldn't need to define it in any class I would define.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the fact that when defining `system` you pass `Component1` as a `line` argument in constructor. Since python does all the operations he can and not checking for the argument types if the operation can be done legally, this passes.

Maybe it would be a nice idea in the system constructor to check if the given argument `lines` is really of type list, and maybe writing something like:

```
    if lines is None or not isinstance(lines, list):
            self.lines = []
    else:
            self.lines = lines
```

That way, you would know about the problem *before* you try appending to the non-list object.

And as for the second part of your question, you can do it exactly like you suggested:

```
system1 = system([Component1, Component2, MyComponent], [])
```

(if you, for example, want to make a system with 3 components, and an empty list as an "console" for lines)

Comment: Python is perfectly capable aggregating a list of arguments automatically, and there is no reason to pass an empty list.