# tuple error on writing properties of a class

Tags: python, tuples

as I am new to the stackoverflow community, I didnt know if I should post this as a new question or continuation of the question I asked here [error with appending to a file and using an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7108378/error-with-appending-to-a-file-and-using-an-array).

It's basically the same code from there only with an extra line:

```
    class component(object):

      def __init__(self,
                   name = None,
                   height = None,                 
                   width = None):

        self.name = name        
        self.height = height
        self.width = width


class system(object):

      def __init__(self,
                   name = None,                 
                   lines = None,
                   *component,
                   **kwargs):

                    self.name = kwargs.get('name')
                    self.component = component
                    self.lines = kwargs.get('lines') or []


      def writeTOFile(self,*component):

                    self.component = component

                    line =" "
                    self.lines.append(line)

                    line= "#----------------------------------------- SYSTEM ---------------------------------------#" 
                    self.lines.append(line)


                    line = "Width = %d" % component.width
                    self.lines.append(line)


      def writeFile(self):

                    ef = open('file1.d', 'w')
                    ef.write('\n'.join(self.lines))
                    ef.close()

Component1 = component ( name = 'C1',
                         height = 500,
                         width = 400)
Component2 = component ( name = 'C2',
                         height = 600,
                         width = 700)
Component_list = [Component1, Component2]                      
system1 = system(Component_list)
system1.writeTOFile(Component_list)
system1.writeFile()
```

The line I added was this:

```
line = "Width = %d" % component.width
self.lines.append(line)
```

The error I get is this :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Work\trial2.py", line 55, in <module>
    system1.writeTOFile(Component_list)
  File "C:\Python27\Work\trial2.py", line 37, in writeTOFile
    line = "Width = %d" % component.width
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'width'
```

The class component clearly has a property called width, so I don't see why this error appears.
I understand that the component is an array of components, so this could be the cause... but I tried to work with a for in the range of (component) but clearly I lack the skills to make it work.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is this:

```
Component_list = [Component1, Component2]                      
system1 = system(Component_list)
```

Combined with this:

```
  def __init__(self,
               name = None,                 
               lines = None,
               *component,
               **kwargs):
```

Either leave off the star in the `__init__`, or do

```
system1 = system(Component1, Component2)
```

without grouping them into a list first.

Also, your `__init__` is wrong again, you've undone the changes I suggested in my answer to your last question. You need it to look like:

```
def __init__(self, *component, **kwargs):
    self.name = kwargs.get('name')
    self.component = component
    self.lines = kwargs.get('lines', [])
```

or the same without the `*` if you put those `component`s into a list as you've done.

Then, instead of

```
def writeTOFile(self,*component):

                self.component = component
```

just do

```
def writeTOFile(self):
```

because you've already added `component` to `self` in `__init__`.

Then, instead of

```
                line = "Width = %d" % component.width
                self.lines.append(line)
```

do

```
            for component in components:
                line = "Width = %d" % component.width
                self.lines.append(line)
```

and everything should work.

Comment: not exactly. his `__init__` is severely bruised. if he's using **kwargs, he doesn't need the named parameters `name` and `lines`

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice he'd moved them back from the changes I made in my last answer. Thanks.

Comment: ok guys! thanks! I think I was seriously confused about several things.

Comment: ok thanks!I didn't want to undo the changes you made to my init.In fact I thought you gave me a quick answer and didn't include my lines as well.. so that's why I added them again lol.I was really not familiar with kwargs or * before this.

Answer (score 0):

Argument ***component**  is a tuple. Moreover you are passing to writeToFile a list of Components, while inside your method you are using passed argument as a Component.

```
for x in component:
            for c in x:
               line = "width = %d" % c.width
               self.lines.append(line)
```